# Why doesn't the list set to italic in div

Tags: css

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why doesn't the list set to Italic as a class in div?

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
font:62.5% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1{
font:small-caps 1.6em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.recipe .intro{
font:italic 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Recipes for Cheese</h1>

<p class="intro">Cheese is a remarkably versatile food, available in literally hundreds of         varieties with different flavors and textures.</p>

<div class="recipe">

<h2>Welsh Rarebit</h2>

<p class="intro">Cheese is a remarkably versatile food, availalbe in literally hundreds of varieties with different flavors and textures.</p>

<ol>
<li>Lightly toast the bread</li>
<li>Place on a baking tray, and spread with butter.</li>
<li>Add the grated Cheddar cheese and 2 tablespoons of beer to a saucepan. Place the saucepan over a medium heat, and stir the cheese continuously until it has melted. Add a teaspoon of wholegrain mustard and grind in a little pepper. Keep stirring.</li>
<li>When thick and smooth, pour over each piece of taost spreading it to the edges to stop the toast from burning.</li>
<li>Place under the grill for a couple of minutes or until golden brown.</li>
</ol>
</div>    
</body>
```

Isn't the order list should be italic since it's in class Recipe. 
Please explain why it isn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<li>` doesnt inherit the properties of the css class `.recipe`, in order to apply it you have to do the following:

```
.recipe li{
    font:italic 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Same happens with the tag `<a>`, you have to apply the value you need in the `.css`

[You can check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dKxyZ/1/)

[If you wanna get more info, check this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font)

Comment: So class recipe has no meaning in this code, it doesn't seem to do anything so might as well use without it. I've tried to take the class recipe out and just give <div> ....</div> and it does the same job.

Comment: It depends, for example, if you want a specific `<li>` that is contain inside a `<div class="recipe">` with this type of `font-style`, then you have to do this, for the other `<li>`s outside that `.recipe`, it's content its not going to be _italic_

Answer (score 1):

Only `.recipe .intro` (your paragraph tag) has `font:italic 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` applied. For all of `.recipe` to have that font, remove `.intro`.

`.recipe .intro` says: "for all elements that have the `intro` class that are decendants of all elements that have the `recipe` class, apply these styles."

Comment: Yes but the lists are in <div class=recipe> so shouldn't it be italic? sorry don't really get it.

Comment: But your CSS is only targeting the `<p class="intro">` elements, not any lists inside `<div class="recipe">`.

Comment: the style was not to .recipe, but .intro; the innermost has upper hand. create another selector for 
     .recipe {font:italic....}